# How to get attribute values of an object stored in $_SESSION?

Tags: php

I have this code that store a "student" object in $_SESSION:

```
if(isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["note"]) && isset($_POST["year"]))
    {
        $nom = $_POST["name"];
        $note = $_POST["note"];
        $session = $_POST["year"];

            $vec = array("name" => $name, "note" => $note, "year" => $year);
            $_SESSION["students"][] = $vec;
            echo "The student has been added.<br><br>";
    }
```

Then I have this code in another page:

```
function calculateAverage()
    {
        $av = 0;
        $count = 0;
        foreach($_SESSION['students'] as $student)
        {
            $av = $av + $student["note"];
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
        return $av / $count;
    }

    function bestNote()
    {
        //$best = array_search(max())
        return $best;
    }

    function worstNote()
    {
        $worst = min(array_search(["note"], $_SESSION['students']));
        return $worst;
    }


    if(isset($_SESSION['students']))
    {
        echo "The average note of the group is = " . calculateAverage() . "\n";
        echo "The one with the best note is " . bestNote()["name"] . " is " . hauteNote()["note"] . " points.\n";
        echo "The one with the worst note is " . worstNote()["name"] . " with " . basseNote()["note"] . " points.\n";
    }
```

As you can see, it is not finished. What I want to do is to be able to get the note of a student that is stored in $_SESSION["students"]. How can I do this?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: `foreach($_SESSION['students'] as $item) { echo $item['name']; }` ?

Answer (score 0):

you can access the stored values within a nested array like so:

```
$studentNote = $_SESSION["students"][YourActiveStudent]["note"];
```

However, you are currently not adding but overwriting data. Use [array_push()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp) to add data to an array (your students).

And when adding a student to the array, make sure to give it a name to make it associative so you can simply "call a student":

```
$_SESSION["students"][$nom] = $vec;
```

this way, if the $nom was "Max", you could say

```
$_SESSION["students"]["Max"]["note"]
```

to get Max's note (BTW, I assume you are talking about grades or marks, rather than notes?)

Comment: `$_SESSION` is a super global variable anyways... you never ever need to specify it like that. You need to make sure he starts the session if he wants to access the data contained within. (With `session_start()`)

Comment: Oh, I thought I had come across configurations where it hadn't been super global (hence my phrasing "depending on your circumstances")... I removed it now.